# Как лучше расставить знаки?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, кавычки

Помогите расставить знаки. Немного торможу. Как лучше? Смысл, что выражение лица героя говорило: "Будем что-то объяснять или поедем?" Нужны ли кавычки?

> Он смотрит на меня, с выражением «будем что-то объяснять или
> поедем»?
>
> или
>
> Он смотрит на меня, с выражением — будем что-то объяснять или
> поедем?

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта годятся.

Есть ещё третий и четвёртый — на усмотрение автора.

*Он смотрит на меня, с выражением: «Будем что-то объяснять или поедем?».*

*Он смотрит на меня, с выражением: будем что-то объяснять или поедем?*

Мне больше последний по вкусу.